# Add text to a paragraph when hover over an image jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to add text to my paragraph section when I hover over a certain image on my page. I am using jQuery to do this. Here is the code I have:

`$(document).ready(function() 
    {
    $('#image that is mouse is hovering over').hover(function() 
    {
           $( this ).append("

text to add

" );
    }
    });'

New code:

```
$('#drg5000').hover(function() {
$('p').prepend("text i want to add" );}
        , function() {
$('p:last').remove();
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the documentation for hover() you'll see that it is a two part function, one for mouseover, one for mouseleave -

```
$( "#image" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).append('<p>text</p>');
}, function() {
    $( this ).find('p:last').remove();
});
```

You're missing the second function of the hover.

Comment: I think I might be missing what exactly I need to put in place of #image...my image has an id (id="drg5000"). Do I use that or the actual image src (images/drg5000.gif)?

Comment: If the id is drg5000 then the selector is $('#drg5000')

Comment: Keep in mind that if you append text to an image that you will not see that text in your browser, but you would be able to see it in the console or DOM inspector.

Comment: Actually here is what I have now. Not trying to add anything to the image but to the "paragraph" when you mouseover, and then the text gets removed. {
  $('#drg5000').hover(function() {
   $('p').prepend("sdffffffffffffff" );}
   , function() {
   $('p:last').remove();
   });
 });

Comment: OK - is that not working? In addition, if you're going to post code please put it in the original post as an edit, not in the comments.

Comment: By checking the checkmark next to the answer that you like best.